# Change PivotStyle every next time of Macro Run

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

I want to change the pivot stayle every next time when run dashboard, please suggest for the same coding is:

```
Set rng = ws.Range("A1:" & Split(Cells(, lastcol).Address, "$")(1) & lastrow)
srcdata = rng.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)
Set pvtch = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(xlDatabase, srcdata)
Set pvtbl = pvtch.CreatePivotTable(tableDestination:=ptws.Range("A3"), tablename:="PivotTable1")
pvtbl.PivotFields("TAT Status").Orientation = xlRowField
pvtbl.PivotFields("RequestType").Orientation = xlRowField
pvtbl.PivotFields("Case Owner").Orientation = xlColumnField
pvtbl.AddDataField pvtbl.PivotFields("Reference no"), "Count_Ticket_ID", xlCount
ptws.Range("A4").Value = "Ticket Type with TAT"
pvtbl.TableStyle2 = "PivotStyleDark1" 'Here I want to change the style every next time when pivot table create.
```

Comment: Sorry. Can you please be a little more clear. Are you expecting 'pvtbl.TableStyle2' to change every time this macro run?

Comment: yes, here we can change the last number i.e. 2 @siva

Comment: yes, in excel we have 28 table style in medium table (pivotstylemedium1 to pivotstylemedium28) and dark table (pivotstyledark1 to pivotstyledark28), now i wanted to change every time whenever new (i.e. next dashboard run time) pivot create it use different style from medium1 to dark28 (total 56 styles) @Siva

Comment: I understand it a bit changing the style wan be achieved by replacing static text with variable pvtbl.TableStyle2 = "PivotStyleDark" & i or pvtbl.TableStyle2 = varPivotStyle (this can be changed) My question is The line of code you gave is it a common fucntion you call every time you want to create a new table or it is part of main sub where these lines are inside any loops. Will be great helpful if you can put entire code and clear scenario for us to help

Comment: This part of main code, the code is too big so i am unable to to put it @Siva